# Why FOP crashed on big files?

Tags: java, xslt, apache-fop

We print on Fop.0.9.4. Windows 10 system. Xml file 1.5mb size (not very big).

In xml file this structure:

```
<root>
 <element />
 <element />
 <element />
 <element />
... 3000 elements or more
</root>
```

In xslt file we write

```
<for-each select="root/element">
 <block-container>
  <some-simple-elements>
 </block-container>
</for-each>
```

If count of pages less 500, than fop is worked, but if 501 pages or more print is crashed.

On log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractLayoutManager.addChildLM(AbstractLayoutManager.java:317)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractLayoutManager.addChildLMs(AbstractLayoutManager.java:331)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractLayoutManager.createNextChildLMs(AbstractLayoutManager.java:291)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.LMiter.hasNext(LMiter.java:40)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractLayoutManager.getChildLM(AbstractLayoutManager.java:115)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableCellLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(TableCellLayoutManager.java:162)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager.createElementsForRowGroup(TableContentLayoutManager.java:490)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager.getKnuthElementsForRowIterator(TableContentLayoutManager.java:251)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(TableContentLayoutManager.java:179)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(TableLayoutManager.java:243)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.BlockContainerLayoutManager$BlockContainerBreaker.getNextKnuthElements(BlockContainerLayoutManager.java:612)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.getNextBlockList(AbstractBreaker.java:551)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.doLayout(AbstractBreaker.java:301)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.BlockContainerLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElementsAbsolute(BlockContainerLayoutManager.java:509)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.BlockContainerLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(BlockContainerLayoutManager.java:195)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.StaticContentLayoutManager$StaticContentBreaker.getNextKnuthElements(StaticContentLayoutManager.java:317)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.getNextBlockList(AbstractBreaker.java:551)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.doLayout(AbstractBreaker.java:301)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.StaticContentLayoutManager.doLayout(StaticContentLayoutManager.java:239)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.layoutSideRegion(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:407)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.finishPage(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:415)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.makeNewPage(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:377)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.handleBreakTrait(PageBreaker.java:492)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.startPart(PageBreaker.java:398)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.addAreas(AbstractBreaker.java:420)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.addAreas(AbstractBreaker.java:370)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.doPhase3(PageBreaker.java:262)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.doLayout(AbstractBreaker.java:345)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use 64 bit Java Runtime**

If you are running 32 bit Java Runtime, the maximum heap size is 1024. But with 64 bit it can go as high as your CPU RAM. For my case, I need to set to 9216MB and I can render up to 5,000 pages of PDF.